# Spring/JNDI with multiple dataSources: ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found

Tags: oracle, spring, jpa, jndi, openjpa

Current Spring application require to setup multiple datasources with JNDI. 
So here is my primary configuration:

In Context.xml/vFabric tc

```
<Resource name="jdbc/app_A" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@myhost:1521:orcl"
    username="usernameA" password="passwordA" maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" maxWait="-1" />
<Resource name="jdbc/app_B" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@myhost:1521:orcl"
    username="usernameB" password="usernameB" maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" maxWait="-1" />
```

In Web.xml of the application:

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>Oracle Datasource for app_A</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/app_A</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
<resource-ref>
    <description>Oracle Datasource for app_B</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/app_B</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

In ApplicationContext.xml

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource1" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/app_A" resource-ref="true" />
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource2" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/app_B" resource-ref="true" />
```

And finally I get exception piled up like this:

```
Jan 31, 2013 3:36:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener addResource
WARNING: Failed to register in JMX: javax.naming.NamingException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

Jan 31, 2013 3:36:56 PM org.apache.naming.NamingContext lookup
WARNING: Unexpected exception resolving reference
java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:412)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:531)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:221)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:503)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:278)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:699)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:631)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:485)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:143)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:116)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:103)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.createDataSource(DataSourceFactory.java:539)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance(DataSourceFactory.java:237)
at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:143)
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:304)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:843)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:831)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.addResource(NamingContextListener.java:1061)
at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.createNamingContext(NamingContextListener.java:671)
at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.lifecycleEvent(NamingContextListener.java:270)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5173)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:618)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1100)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1618)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found

at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:385)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1042)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:301)
... 38 more
Jan 31, 2013 3:36:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener addResource
WARNING: Failed to register in JMX: javax.naming.NamingException: Listener refused the  connection with the following error:
ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found

Jan 31, 2013 3:36:56 PM org.apache.naming.NamingContext lookup
WARNING: Unexpected exception resolving reference
java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found
```

Really not sure why the "no appropriate service handler found" error pop up, it seems the connection is not accepted/understood by orcl Listener.

Here is what I insert into persisntence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit1">
....
<jta-data-source>jdbc/app_A</jta-data-source>
....
</persistence-unit>

<persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit2">
....
<jta-data-source>jdbc/app_B</jta-data-source>
....
</persistence-unit>
```

Here are some interesting finding and confusion:

1. I use jdbc url "jdbc:oracle:thin:@myhost:1521:orcl" with SQL Developer to setup a connection, and when I test it, sometimes it get connected without issue, but sometimes it launches the same issue: "appropriate service handler found". However, the same jdbc url works fine with previous Spring application. So what is the trick?
2. How to deploy multiple data sources using JNDI? Can we give multiple  tag as solution, just like I did in the context.xml?

Thanks in advance for any advices.

### UPDATE 1

I revert one of the datasources as regular jdbc data connection and leave the other one as JNDI, and now the application runs like a charm. So definitely the problem is caused by multiple datasources, I bet there should be specific config protocol to make more than one jndi datasources work together. If both datasources come from same database(same url) but different scheme(username/password), so what is the correct syntax to configure the parameters?

Comment: Do these multiple Data sources belong to same or different database?

Comment: @Piyush. Thank you, then belong to the same database, just different schema.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Find the problem is caused by Oracle memory overflow, from JNDI setup:

```
maxActive="20" maxIdle="10"
```

That is too many connections ask for Oracle to provide. Unless Oracle server is setup with excessive connections that testing environment can spend, it is better to narrow down as

```
maxActive="1" maxIdle="1"
```

So modify the active number, restart the application (and restart oracle if get that ora error), the issue should not happen. Cheers.